# Do third-party packages have to be installed in the project folder?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm currently using PyCharm to create a simple Alexa and to do that I need to have the speak recognition package installed.

I've used the `pip install SpeechRecognition` and I'm getting module not found error and I'm wondering if it would be easier to download the package in the project directory as it's currently installed in site-packages.

Comment: "Easier" is a completely different thing from from "have to be". "Have to be" has a simple answer, "no". What's _easy_ is subjective / subject to opinion.

Comment: There are two rules; following them both will simplify your life. (1) Make sure you only do the `pip install` once you're in a virtualenv created for your project. (2) Make sure you have PyCharm configured to use that virtualenv. (Personally, I use Nix rather than virtualenv at all, but that's a much heavier lift).

Comment: I would call vendoring Python libraries into your codebase _harder_ than installing them properly, because library authors don't expect them to be installed that way, so it's an untested installation mode and prone to causing complications whenever a library depends on C modules or otherwise has an interesting or unusual installation mechanism.